# How to find out which graphcs card my libgdx/lwjgl game is running on?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx, lwjgl

Using an laptop that has multiple graphics cards, I wonder which one is being used by my libGDX / LWJGL game. How can I find out? Are there any built-in functions?

There seem to be some information providing methods in `com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx.graphics` but so far I only got stuff like the display resolution and GL version etc.

Comment: Is [glGetString](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetString.xhtml) with parameters `GL_VENDOR` and `GL_RENDERER` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Erdal Küçük's comment I found the solution for libGDX:

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;

Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glGetString(GL20.GL_VENDOR);
Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glGetString(GL20.GL_RENDERER);
```

See https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetString.xhtml